# Import error with spacy: "No module named en"

Tags: python, spacy

I'm having trouble using the Python [spaCy library](https://spacy.io/). It seems to be installed correctly but at

```
from spacy.en import English
```

I get the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spacy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from spacy.en import English
  File "/home/user/CmdData/spacy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from spacy.en import English
ImportError: No module named en
```

I'm not very familiar with Python but that's the standard import I saw online, and the library is installed:

```
$ pip list | grep spacy
spacy (0.99)
```

**EDIT**
I tested renaming the file, but that's not the problem. I also get the same error when doing:

```
$ python -m spacy.en.download --force all
/usr/bin/python: No module named en
```

(The command is supposed to download some models)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are facing this error because you named your own file `spacy.py`. Rename your file, and everything should work.

Comment: Do you have a `spacy.pyc` file in the same directory form where you are running the command? If so, delete it.

Comment: @TheCodingMonk Can I follow up and ask how did you solve the problem? I had the same problem but don't understand the conversations above. Thanks !

Answer (score 18):

For windows, open cmd with admin right. Then,

```
python -m spacy download en
```

You should see the shell prompt stating.

*You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')*

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me (on Linux as well)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and the problem was the folder where the module 'en' was stored (spacy/lang/en).

Typing:

from spacy.lang.en import English

fixed the issue.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295316/importerror-no-module-named-spacy-en) was helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: I was looking for the new location for stopwords in Spacy and your post was helpful. 
from spacy.lang.en import STOP_WORDS as STOPWORDS

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the version of Python at `/usr/bin/python` is not the one that has spacy installed. If so, navigating to the directory where your 'normal' version of Python is before running

```
python -m spacy.en.download
```

should fix the problem. (For example, I installed spacy using Anaconda and had to navigate to `C:\Anaconda2\` first.)

Answer (score 3):

SpaCy has various models depending on the language of your choice (even contains a multi-language model), so you can have a look at [this link](https://spacy.io/usage/models) to have a better idea on which might suit your needs.

You could also find the correct installation command here. For example, for small  version model for English Language:

> ***python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm***

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This Works!

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```