# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.en'

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I'm suddenly having trouble importing spaCy. It worked yesterday, and I haven't changed anything on my machine or environment, so I have no idea what's happened.  I've read similar questions (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842052/import-error-with-spacy-no-module-named-en)), but I'm getting different traceback messages so the solution there doesn't work.

`from spacy.en import English`

yields the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2406cee3a8c9> in <module>()
----> 1 from spacy.en import English

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.en'
```

That's the entire traceback.

I've tried updating just about everything I can update.  I'm using Python version 3.6.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295316/importerror-no-module-named-spacy-en

Comment: @chrisz - thanks, `spacy.lang.en` worked.