# Python chatboot project in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, chatbot

I want to make a simple chat boot with Python
And I use pycharm but I had a problem with the first commands I used
The package versions do not seem to be compatible

But I do not know the solution, please help

In this project I have installed  python 3.6 and tensorflow 2.3 and ChatterBot 1.0.8 and en 0.0.1 but it gives an error

Do the package versions not match?

mycode:

```
 from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train([
    "Hi, can I help you?",
    "Sure, I'd like to book a flight to Iceland.",
    "Your flight has been booked."
])

# Get a response to the input text 'I would like to book a flight.'
response = chatbot.get_response('I would like to book a flight.')

print(response)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ZYousefi/PycharmProjects/ZYChatBot/CHATTERBOT.py", line 6, in <module>
    chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 21, in __init__
    'tagger_language', languages.ENG
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 170, in load_model
    return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\PycharmProjects\ZYChatBot\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 190, in load_model_from_package
    cls = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\ZYousefi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en'
```

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842052/import-error-with-spacy-no-module-named-en

Comment: Did you install using the Pycharm preferences menu or did you install from the Linux command line?

Comment: I install using the Pycharm preferences menu